# convert java file to kotlin file disabled in Android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.3

After updating android studio 3.3 canary 7 `convert java file to kotlin file is showing disable`.

```
Android Studio Menu -> Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File
```

Its showing disable. Why it is disable and how can i enable it android studio latest version.

Comment: Just try a shortcut key -> Ctrl+Shift+Alt+k in Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

Open your File and press

> Ctrl + Alt + Shift + K

Converting Java Code to Kotlin Code :

- Select your java class file from project structure.
- Android Studio Menu -> **Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File**

Comment: Its disabled that's why asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project to set up again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Kotlin plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26298 . Please update your IDE plugin version to 1.2.61, the problem is fixed there.